# Post Content Displaying Below ALL Shortcodes Content

Tags: theme-development

For some reason, my posts content (the content placed outside of the shortcodes I have set up) is only displaying below all the shortcodes, no matter where I place content in the post.

For example, I could set up a post like this:

`[boxes cat="Features"]`

`test content here`

`[boxes cat="Reviews"]`

And the test content will display below the Features AND the Reviews. Why would it do that? Some of my shortcodes use the php `include`. Here's an example of one of my shortcodes:

```
function free_ms_cms( $atts, $content = null ) {
   $free_ms = TEMPLATEPATH . '/get-free-ms.php';
   include($free_ms);
}
add_shortcode( 'free-ms', 'free_ms_cms' );
```

Anyone able to help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are your shortcodes setup correctly?  This usually means that your shortcode handling is echoing the shortcode content instead of returning it as a string.

For your case, while you are including a file in your shortcode, I doubt that you have the file setup to return the output instead of echo'ing it.

Try this instead:

```
function free_ms_cms( $atts, $content = null ) {
   $free_ms = TEMPLATEPATH . '/get-free-ms.php';
   ob_start(); //start an output buffer to capture any output
   include($free_ms);
   return ob_get_clean(); //return the current buffer and clear it
}
add_shortcode( 'free-ms', 'free_ms_cms' );
```

Comment: My shortcodes are using include, I updated my question with one of my shortcodes. I'm not sure if it returns or echoes with include. If you could check it out and update your answer I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I know what you mean now, I've solved my own question with your help. :)

Comment: @Jared: post the solution as an answer for future lurking guests.

Comment: @Jared, I've updated the answer to include code for your particular instance.